# Why the value for count doesn't change

Tags: java, integer

I know it is a very simple question and I am new to programing, It brothers me for few hours..
the following is my code, I really don't know why the of count doesn;t changes as the function goes

```
public class Solution {
    public int totalNQueens(int n) {
        int count =4;
        boolean[] col = new boolean[n];
        boolean[] dia1 = new boolean[2*n];
        boolean[] dia2 = new boolean[2*n];
        backtrack(0, col, dia1, dia2,count,n);
        return count;
    }

    private void backtrack(int rownum, boolean[] col, boolean[] dia1, boolean[] dia2, int count,int n){
        count =5;
        if(rownum==n){
            count++;
        }else{
            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
                int index1 = i-rownum+n;
                int index2 = i+rownum;
                if(col[i]||dia1[index1]||dia2[index2]) continue;
                col[i]=true; dia1[index1]=true; dia2[index2]=true;
                backtrack(rownum+1, col,dia1,dia2,count,n);
                col[i]=false; dia1[index1]=false; dia2[index2]=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your totalNQueens function, you set count to 4... And then you return it.  Once you call the backtrack function, it's a "different" count that doesn't alter the count  variable in totalNQueens.  There are several ways to resolve it, the easiest being to make your backtrack method a function that returns "count" at the end.  Or you could make count a class variable.

Edit: I should refer you to look up "scope of variables."

Edit 2: Try this, instead:

```
public class Solution {
    public int totalNQueens(int n) {
        int count =4;
        boolean[] col = new boolean[n];
        boolean[] dia1 = new boolean[2*n];
        boolean[] dia2 = new boolean[2*n];
        return backtrack(0, col, dia1, dia2,count,n);
    }

    private int backtrack(int rownum, boolean[] col, boolean[] dia1, boolean[] dia2, int count,int n){
        if(rownum==n){
            count++;
        }else{
            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
                int index1 = i-rownum+n;
                int index2 = i+rownum;
                if(col[i]||dia1[index1]||dia2[index2]) continue;
                col[i]=true; dia1[index1]=true; dia2[index2]=true;
                count = backtrack(rownum+1, col,dia1,dia2,count,n);
                col[i]=false; dia1[index1]=false; dia2[index2]=false;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

There are some problems, here, though.  You are using recursion.  I think your code is not going to do what you want because you are setting count=5 as the first line of "backtrack."  I'm guessing that's for debugging purposes, just to see it change your return value, but of course it was only affecting the "instance" of "count" in backtrack, and not totalNQueens.  So I removed it, because I don't think it's actually part of your algorithm.  It may also be wrong to set count where I am setting it in your backtrack function... I don't know your algorithm (although I can guess the problem you are solving).

Again, I implore you to look up "variable scope."

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, but I still don;t understand why the count in the totalNQueens is a different variable than the count i declared at the very beginning...

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding exactly where you are saying count doesn't change. If you only look at the return value of totalNQueens, it looks like it will always be 4 because of variable scope. Or, are you saying that in "backtrack" it doesn't change to 5 or 6 (the first iteration)?  Because how would you know that unless you are running through a debugger or printing the value somewhere, in which case you are not giving us all the code.

Comment: I am saying, though, that no matter what you pass to totalNQueens, it will always return 4.  You are declaring a new and different variable called "count" in your backtrack function.